# 3 ways of binding this keywords in react using es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know there are 3 ways to declare a method within a class. I used to use React.create class but I decided to go with the hype where I write in newer syntax - ES6.

I admit I have little about es6. There are 3 ways of bind this keyword.

1.

```
class myClass extends Components {
    constructor(props){
        super()
        this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this)
    }
    doSomething(){
    }
    render(){
       return(<div onClick={this.doSomething}>click me</div>)
    }
}
```

2.

```
class myClass extends Components {
    constructor(props){
        super()
    }
    doSomething(){
    }
    render(){
       return(<div onClick={this.doSomething.bind(this)}>click me</div>)
    }
}
```

3.

```
class myClass extends Components {
    constructor(props){
        super()
    }
    doSomething(){
    }
    render(){
       return(<div onClick={e => this.doSomething}>click me</div>)
    }
}
```

My question is how these different ways of doing things different from each other?

Comment: All explanations here: https://medium.com/@housecor/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56#.bddf7b3h5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, option 1 binds `this` in the constructor, so that the binding only happens once for each usage of a component. This comes at the expense of having to write a constructor, which might not have otherwise been necessary.

Option 2 and 3 achieve the same thing using different syntax, creating a new function with `this` bound every time the component is rendered.

Your option 3 should actually call the function `doSomething`, i.e. `e => this.doSomething()`. Personally I would either pass the event `e` to the function or change `e` to `()` to make it clear that the anonymous function wasn't using any parameters.

The first option is slightly more efficient, as you're not creating a new function on every render but I tend to go with option 3 because it looks nicer and I've never noticed any real performance problems with it. Up to you.

---

As an aside, if you use `createClass` then React handles the binding of `this` in your methods for you, which is something to consider when evaluating which method to go with.

Comment: option 3 is the fastest way to get the job done, you don't have to scroll up and bind something.

Answer (score 0):

As your question.

**Method 1** *is using function defined in constructor.*

This method is a mix of the previous one with usage of class constructor function.

You don’t have to use `bind()` inside your **JSX** anymore, but this comes with the cost of increasing the size of constructor code.

**Method 2** *is using of Function.prototype.bind().*

As any method of ES6 class is plain JavaScript function it inherits `bind()` from Function prototype. So now when we call `increaseQty()` inside **JSX**, this will point to our class instance. You could read more about `Function.prototype.bind()` in this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

**Method 3** *is using fat arrow function and constructor.*

ES6 fat arrow functions preserve this context when they are called. We could use this feature and redefine `doSomething()` inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

these are examples of scoped functions.

```
https://ariya.io/2013/05/es6-and-block-scope
```

so for the first instance

`onClick={this.doSomething}`

onClick is outside scope from the class. so binding is required. so calling this inside it will refer to the React element (div)

second instance

`onClick={this.doSomething.bind(this)}`

basically the same.  now you bind `this` from the caller of the onClick. which happens to be the class.

third instance

`onClick={e => this.doSomething}`

using arrows changes the context of the function, so from `this` refering to div, it becomes `this` referring to class

bonus instance

`doSomething = () => {}`

call it like

`onClick={ this.doSomething }`

Comment: im not asking what they are.

Comment: just answered your question. how are they different from each other. well anyways nice attitude :)